# Hibernate: How configure entity to be inserted/updated/deleted through Oracle package procedures?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible (and if yes, how?) to map entity class to be fetched from table, but inserted/updated/deleted through procedures, instead of doing `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on this table?

Entity configuration is done via XML, and using classes/methods specific to Oracle is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map custom SQL for create/update/delete operations since [version 3.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud).

If you want to map through regular SQL statements, you can just write SQL normally inside the `<sql-insert>`, `<sql-update>`, `<sql-delete>` elements.

When using stored procedures, you need to mark them as callable statements and use the call syntax. Note the required out parameters for delete and update, returning the amount of rows removed.

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
    <sql-insert callable="true">{call createPerson (?, ?)}</sql-insert>
    <sql-delete callable="true">{? = call deletePerson (?)}</sql-delete>
    <sql-update callable="true">{? = call updatePerson (?, ?)}</sql-update>
</class>
```